# Is there a function that will remove any symbols (%, #, & ect.) from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove ALL symbols from my string efficiently.

```
x = hello!!
r = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n ' + string.punctuation))
x.translate(r)
```

I expected this to remove all symbols instead of only a full stop (.)

Comment: What dou mean by symbols? Do you want to keep only ascii-chars? Only letters and numbers?

Comment: Yeah, I would like to keep letters and numbers and remove all other characters such as punctuation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `re.sub` to remove all `string.punctuation` and `' \n'`:

```
x = re.sub('|'.join(map(re.escape, string.punctuation + ' \n')), '', x)
```

You could also use the following regex if you want to keep only alphabet and digit characters:

```
x = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', x)
```